Custom Function Filters
I have a function that currently uses 3 parameters:
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RatesReport (@StartTapeDate DATE, @StartFcbVersionId int, @StartSvbVersionId int)
SELECT *
FROM dbo.DataTapes t
WHERE t.TapeDate = @StartTapeDate AND t.VersionId IN(@StartFcbVersionId, @StartSvbVersionId) 

I'd like to add an additional parameter (@LoanType int) that further bifurcates the data but it would need to be derived.
CASE WHEN t.SecId LIKE 'CD_%' THEN 1 ELSE 2
So that my new query/function would look something like this:
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RatesReport (@StartTapeDate DATE, @StartFcbVersionId int, @StartSvbVersionId int, @DataType int)
SELECT *
FROM dbo.DataTapes t
WHERE t.TapeDate = @StartTapeDate AND t.VersionId IN(@StartFcbVersionId, @StartSvbVersionId) and t.SecId = @LoanType


for that you would use dynamic sql https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

@nbk No you wouldn't.

@J.D. then you didn't understand the question

@nbk Not true, since I've provided an applicable solution that doesn't require dynamic SQL. I think perhaps you're confused.

If I understand what you're saying correctly, why couldn't you just write that expression in your function's body like so?
SELECT *
FROM dbo.DataTapes t
WHERE t.TapeDate = @StartTapeDate
    AND t.VersionId IN(@StartFcbVersionId, @StartSvbVersionId)
    AND CASE WHEN t.SecId LIKE 'CD_%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END = @LoanType

It's not the most performant solution, but probably least of your problems if you plan to use SELECT * and possibly a multi-statement table valued function, both of which hurt performance. (Hard to tell what type of function you're trying to write with the example code provided as it's missing necessary syntax.)

Why not just AND (t.SecId LIKE 'CD_%' AND @LoanType = 1 OR t.SecId NOT LIKE 'CD_%' AND @LoanType = 2) seems more logical (not counting null handling)

@Charlieface ‍♂️. Just easiest to show OP that the code they want to use can be used in their function. Perhaps more readable for someone newer like OP. And can be expanded to handle more than 2 types easily. But yea, I'd personally normally write something similar to what you wrote, for my own code.
